# Azure Data Factory Dataflow Transpose Array<Struct> Column to Single Row with Index Suffixed Columns

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to transpose an array of structs to a single row per `ID` with an index suffixed column for each field in the structs.

**Given:**

| ID | COORDINATES |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ {"x": 47, "y": 102}, {"x": 2, "y": 98} ] |
| 2 | [ {"x": 23, "y": 41} ] |

**Expected:**

| ID | x_1 | y_1 | x_2 | y_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 47 | 102 | 2 | 98 |
| 2 | 23 | 41 |  |  |

**Question:**

How can I efficiently achieve my Expected results using `Azure Data Factory Dataflows`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Flatten transformation to unroll your array first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VY2tFQJoAXE

Then, you can build your target schema using a Derived Column after that transformation